# How to find out a website is created with such and such language?

Tags: web-development-server

For Eg..(.HTML gives an idea of that website developed with HTML, .aspx gives an idea of 
that website developed with ASP.NET and so on...). But, if extension is hidden, then can we able to find out in any other way? Is it possible to know ?..Thanks..

Comment: Frameworks like django allows you to send the html response without any file name at all - there's no perfect way to know for sure.

Comment: I think this is more for the realm for l33t. And indeed, there is no perfect way for this unless access to the source. Thus, a hackerish answer is needed here.

Comment: Well, in that case if /javascripts/applications.js exists, you can fetch it, download it and see the Ruby On Rails comments. If not, it isn't Rails (unless it is changed by the developer) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually by error codes, and behavior. However, I have to say that a webpage these days is not just 'one' technology, but a soup. Example, the back-end can be a database (MySQL, Postgre, MS SQL), which is usually accessed through SQL statements fed to an adapter/connector, but could also be taken care of by a framework (RubyOnRails, Zend, etc) using ActiveRecord (ORM). The server-side part is usually 'discovered' by extension (php/asp), but in RubyOnRails extensions are no longer part of the site because of most MVC frameworks allow friendly urls (which are good for SEO). Then there is the CSS for the page layout and JavaScript for dynamic features such as AJAX. Unless you have access to the source code, the only other way to figure it out is to try banner grabbing/tampering. Which means like requesting pages with false data and try to get some sort of error to figure out what is running server side.

Example: if the error handling is not taken care of by the developer, you try an invalid id number as url parameter. On a Ruby-on-Rails app, you'll get the standard exception screen. On CodeIgniter, you get a similar page, it would look different because of its templates.

www.mysite.com/myproducts/29292020929912919292992222222222992929299922012000101019292

Comment: Excellent...Nice...really superb answer...but here also 1 exception which is "Exception Handling". If Exception Handling is not taken care by the developer, we can find out as u said...Any way...Thanks for ur nice answer..

Comment: -1: I don't agree. Any good website will not directly show message from the underlying framework. In fact, good frameworks allow to specify custom error page to which it is redirected on error.

Comment: 1. Not everybody uses a framework.
2. I said 'if the error handling is not taken care of by the developer', in its respect means not customizing. The answer to the question is a 'hacking' answer. Which means, one of the methods a hacker would use to identify the technology behind a website. 
Sad that you have downvoted the answer, merely for not reading my answer in its full.

Comment: Friend @Shyam! No need to be sad for the down vote. Voting feature in this website is for this purpose only. I didn't agreed, so I down voted. Many others may agree or disagree. They will vote accordingly. That is the only way to know how widely acceptable the answer is. You didn't loose millions dollars on that. It's just 2 points on reputation. If anyone will agree with your answer, they will up vote and you will recover 10 points on reputation. Basically, I down voted because this answer will not help on a good website.

Answer (score 5):

In theory nothing in the HTTP response reveals for sure which language was used to generate the content. It could even be the case that the content of an url ending with .php is generated by, say, JSP for instance.

Perhaps there are some funny hacks out there, that could reveal it in some cases. I suppose for instance that if the URL points to some directory (ends with ".com" or "something/") you could try appending index.php, index.asp, or whatever to see what works.

Comment: Yes, you can never know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the extension is .aspx, one cannot guarantee that it is built on ASP.NET and the same is with .php, .asp etc.

Answer (score 0):

Search the website for a link that says "Contact us."  Use email and phone information contained to contact the people who own the website.  Ask them.

If they do not know, go to whois.net or a similar service.  Enter the domain address.  Jot down the information about who owns and manages the website.  Copy down their phone numbers and email addresses.  Contact them and ask.

In all of these, be polite and complimentary.  If they think you admire their work, they might reveal some details.